# Scraping with rvest and converting html output into data frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

When scraping Bombay Stock Exchange Website for financial results in R, I get and html code.

```
read_html("https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/TabResults/w?scripcode=500470&tabtype=RESULTS") %>% 
    html_text()
```

However I get output as below:

```
[1] "\"{\\\"col1\\\":\\\"(in Cr.)\\\",\\\"col2\\\":\\\"Sep-18\\\",\\\"col3\\\":\\\"Jun-18\\\",\\\"col4\\\":\\\"FY17-18\\\",\\\"resultinCr\\\":[{\\\"title\\\":\\\"Revenue\\\",\\\"v1\\\":\\\"17,902.04\\\",\\\"v2\\\":\\\"16,405.46\\\",\\\"v3\\\":\\\"60,519.37\\\"},....
```

How should I extract these data into data frame?

I tried using `gsub` to extract numbers and characters from the text output. But backslash characters make it difficult.
The table format should be like this:

[image: Table Snapshot]

Comment: The API is returning of JSON, not HTML, which you can see if you open it in a web browser. If you use `jsonlite::fromJSON` instead of `read_html`, you for some reason get a string of JSON instead of a parsed result, so you need to re-parse: `x <- jsonlite::fromJSON(jsonlite::fromJSON('https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/TabResults/w?scripcode=500470&tabtype=RESULTS'))` ...which is a bit silly, but works. There's surely a more elegant solution if it matters enough to put in the effort.

Comment: Ultra Smooth.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
url<-"https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/TabResults/w?scripcode=500470&tabtype=RESULTS"
library(rvest)
page<-html_session(url)
json<-readBin(page$response$content, what="json")

library(jsonlite)
df<-fromJSON(json)
df<-fromJSON(df)

#Result in CR
df$resultinCr

#result in Million
df$resultinM
```

The result is in JSON format. Parse the JSON by using JSONLITE package.